# Hibernate data consistency

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, consistency

I have java-servlet application +hibernate + streaming server

**Flow:**

1. user login begin video streaming
2. decrement abonament minutes in data base every 2 seconds
3. if minutes < 0 send request for the new minutes(response may be after
   long time, if so continue decrement )

**Problem:**

Appears data consistency problem, other words while decrementing minutes, 
ex: `user.setMinutes(user.getMinutes() - 2)` may not see changes maded by new minutes response, and minutes will be corrupted

I thought sollution could be create new hibernate transaction and commit it every time when I change minutes, but this didn't worked:

```
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
user.setMinutes()
session.flush();
t.commit();
```

**Question:**

How to solve this problem, when each change get most recent data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate session caches your entities in memory (in your case the `User` entity). It's not enough to create a new transaction for changing the remaining minutes, you also have to reload the changes made by other tasks (addditional minutes request). You can achieve this by calling `refresh()`:

```
session.refresh(user);
user.setMinutes(user.getMinutes() - 2);
session.flush();
```

Comment: thank you it's working, also I found this method - session.lock(user, LockMode.READ), what do you think it could be useful here, or session.refresh() will be in off?

Comment: @Sergey: As far as I know, `session.lock()` does not read the database changes back to the entity, I'd stick with `refresh()` is if works.